# Release management in parallel development/testing environment -Deadlock

Tags: version-control

I am in a deadlock. Ours is a product development firm related to health care.We are using SVN version control system.We have multiple customers,each of them has a dedicated development branch. The customer branches are always branched of from trunk.We use trunk as the development branch for one of our premium customer, let's say PC1.

Right now we released a version of our product named PDT_5.0 to PC1. The release happened from Release branch PDT_5.0,which was originaly branched off from trunk.

Bug fixes related to PDT_5.0 release has already started to come in. At the same time Customer has requested some minor features which we promised to deliver in a months time. The new features has been developed in trunk. However before moving to live the new features has to be tested by QA and has to get approval from customer side.

Now the dead lock:
PDT_5.0 is already in live. Bug fixes are happening in Release branch of PDT_5.0.
Feature development is finished.This has to be QA tested. However we cannot wait for QA to finish testing and then release, because urgent bug fixes from live has to be released as fast as possible. I am completely lost here.

The problem is i dont want to branch off from trunk since the features are too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a described process in place, I don't see any other way rather than making selective merge (AKA cherry-picking) of required features and fixes from your trunk and release branches into customer's branch.

Going forward, if you have a business model based on customer-specific features and branches, you need to change a way you deliver your changes.

First option is that you ask your sales people not to promise to deliver features ahead of official release. Seriously. Just say "guys, thank you for selling features which we don't have yet, but please don't make any additional deployment commitments". This way, you'll keep your releases straightforward: trunk -> release branch -> customer branch. After that your dev team migrates specific changes from one old branch to a new one.

Otherwise you should just tune your process to meet this new reality when you have to integrate your bugfixes back and forth until you bury youself under tons of delta pending its integration.

I hope it helps...